# Referential integrity constraint violation when deleting an object with play-framework 2.2.x

Tags: java, jpa, playframework-2.0, h2, ebean

I've designed my database such that I can access a list of purchases (for history) as well as a simple foreign key link to the latest purchase. Everything (basic crud operations) work except for when I try to delete a customer. I've created a small sample project to exemplify the issue I'm having, which I've modeled after the demo [ebean project](https://github.com/ebean-orm-demo/demo-order/blob/master/src/main/java/app/data/Product.java#L12).

**The complete code is posted on [github](https://github.com/desimone/play-framework-ebean-test-project-with-latest-entity).**

The referenced unit test (and any delete) throws the following exception:

**Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK_CUSTOMER_LATESTPURCHASE_1: PUBLIC.CUSTOMER FOREIGN KEY(LATEST_PURCHASE_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.PURCHASE(ID) (2)"; SQL statement: delete from purchase where customer_id = ?**

[Full Stack Trace here](https://gist.github.com/7682303)

## Code

### [Customer Model](https://github.com/desimone/play-framework-ebean-test-project-with-latest-entity/blob/master/app/models/Customer.java)

```
package models;


@Entity
public class Customer extends Model {
    // Modeled after https://github.com/ebean-orm-demo/demo-order/blob/master/src/main/java/app/data/Customer.java#L48-L49
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private boolean valid;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "customer")
    private List<Purchase> purchases;
    @ManyToOne
    private Purchase latestPurchase;


    public void addOrder(Purchase purchase) {
        this.purchases.add(purchase);
        this.setLatestPurchase(purchase);
        purchase.setCustomer(this);
        purchase.save();
    }

    .. standard getters and setters ..
}
```

### [Purchase Model](https://github.com/desimone/play-framework-ebean-test-project-with-latest-entity/blob/master/app/models/Purchase.java)

package models;

```
@Entity
public class Purchase extends Model {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="customer_id")
    private Customer customer;

    .. standard getters and setters ..
}
```

### [Unit Test that fails](https://github.com/desimone/play-framework-ebean-test-project-with-latest-entity/blob/master/test/ModelTest.java)

```
@Test
public void deleteCustomerCascades() {
    running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Customer randy = new Customer("Randy Marsh");
            randy.save();
            // Let's add some purchases for randy
            randy.addOrder(new Purchase("PS4"));
            randy.addOrder(new Purchase("XBOX One Bundulru"));
            //persist
            randy.update();

            Customer retrieved = Customer.find.byId(randy.getId());

            assertThat(retrieved.getLatestPurchase().getName()).isEqualTo("XBOX One Bundulru");
            assertNotNull(retrieved.getId());
            assertEquals(retrieved.getLatestPurchase().getName(),"XBOX One Bundulru");
            // There are 2 total purchases
            assertEquals(Purchase.find.all().size(), 2);
            // And Randy has two.
            assertEquals(retrieved.getPurchases().size(),2);
            // Randy is the owner of both purchases
            assertEquals(randy.getLatestPurchase().getCustomer(),randy);
            for (Purchase purchase : Purchase.find.all()){
                assertEquals(purchase.getCustomer().getName(),"Randy Marsh");
            }
            // Let's delete the customer, and his purchases with it
            retrieved.delete();
            retrieved.update();
            assertThat(Purchase.find.all().size()).isEqualTo(0);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the `orphanRemoval=true` to your OneToMany relationship. Besides, I think you will get another exception when you update `retrieved` after `retrieved.update()`.